# OOP-Java. Adding Animal objects to an Arraylist in the Class from the main

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist

Adding a second Animal, resets the animals Arraylist to index 0. So it holds the last entered animal. I also putted the UML design below, so it might be more understandable what I'm trying.

```
public class Cage {
    private int placeNr;
    private ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    public Cage(int place) {
        this.placeNr = place;
    }

    public int getCageNr() {
        return this.placeNr;
    }


    public void putAnimal(Animal animal) throws DuplicateNameException {
        if(!duplicatedAnimal(animal.getName())) {
            animals.add(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I'm confused. How do I add an Animal class in the an Arraylist located in Cage and stack my Animals in it.

```
private static void addAnimal() {
    Animal newAnimal;
    Cage cage;
    try {
        System.out.println("Name: ");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Type: ");
        String type = sc.next();
        System.out.println("birthYear: ");
        int birthYear = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Cage number: ");
        int cageNumber = sc.nextInt();

        cage = new Cage(cageNumber);
        newAnimal = new Animal(name, type, birthYear);
        cage.putAnimal(newAnimal);
    } catch (DuplicateNameException dne) {
        dne.getMessage();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }
}
```

If someone can push me in the right direction it will be awesome thanks!

UML:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQDYE.png)

Comment: what exactly is the error/problem you facing?

Comment: *"How do I add an Animal class in the an Arraylist "* you do **not** add the *class* `Animal` but *instaces* of it.

Comment: does `cage.putAnimal(newAnimal);` give an error? undesired behaviour? your post isn't clear at all...

Comment: "*Adding a second Animal, resets the animals Arraylist to index 0*" - Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From what you have shown so far, this should not happen.

Comment: How method duplicatedAnimal looks?

Comment: @shahaf the problem im facing is when I create new an animal instace and try to add it to the Arraylist located in class Cage. It adds the animal but when I. Add. An. New one it just starts filling at index 0. So the previous animal doesnt excest anymore. When I use the find Animal method in the main to locate the animals by name it only finds the new added.

Comment: @C.Khan, ok, tried to do something with what I understood so far, hope it what you looking for, let me know if not

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call addAnimal you will create a new Cage object and add the new animal to that cage. To add several animals to the same cage the addAnimal method can not be static and cage needs to be a member of some class (AnimalKeeper?)

Something like this

```
public class AnimalKeeper {
  private Cage cage;

  public Cage getCage() {
      return cage;
  }

  public addAnimalToCage(Animal animal) {
      //the same method as above minus the user input
      //which needs to be done somewhere else
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it an try :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to figure out what you meant exactly, refactor your code to smth like this

```
class DuplicateNameException extends Exception {

    private String message;

    public DuplicateNameException(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }

}

class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


class Cage {
    private int placeNr;

    private ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    public Cage(int place) {
        this.placeNr = place;
    }

    public int getCageNr() {
        return this.placeNr;
    }


    public void putAnimal(Animal animal) throws DuplicateNameException {
        if(!duplicatedAnimal(animal.getName())) {
            animals.add(animal);
        } else {
            throw new DuplicateNameException(animal.getName());
        }
    }

    private boolean duplicatedAnimal(String name) {
        for (Animal animal : animals)
            if (animal.getName().equals(name))
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal newAnimal;
        Cage cage;
        try {
            cage = new Cage(1);
            newAnimal = new Animal("Dog");
            cage.putAnimal(newAnimal);
            cage.putAnimal(new Animal("not dog"));
            cage.putAnimal(new Animal("Dog"));
        } catch (DuplicateNameException dne) {
            System.out.println(dne.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: with this code you need to consider cases with animals name written in lower case and upper case (`equals` will return `false` in this case) use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` to normelize the name to common ground

another option you can take is to use [HashMap](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/) object, this structure type has duplication elimination build in, you will have to override the `hashCode()` function of `Animal` so the `map` will know how to hash each object, like

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return this.name.hashCode()
}
```

Comment: My code looks familiar to this concept. But my main method is located in the Zoo.java class. If i'm right this (cage = new Cage(1)) will put all animals in the same cage right? The question asked by school is this. getAnimal returns an Animal with a specific name or null if such an Animal is not in the Cage. <-- This part returns from the Arraylist in the Cage class only 1 animal even when I add multiple animals to the same Cage 
c. animalInList returns true if an Animal with a provided name is in the Cage
or false otherwise

Comment: @C.Khan `cage = new Cage(1)` this line create a new cage and assign it the number 1, all animal you add using `cage.putAnimal(...)` will be added to this cage, I didn't implement `getAnimal()` cause I didn't saw it in your provided code... but you can implement it fairly easy 
is there another question in your comment?